# Determining poles and order of $1/\sin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I find the poles and the order of $\dfrac{1}{\sin(z)}$?

Answer (score 6):

Well, $ \sin z = 0 $ iff $z = n \pi $  where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Notice

$$ \lim_{z \to n \pi} \frac{ z - n \pi}{\sin z} =_{Lhop} \lim_{z \to n \pi} \frac{ 1}{\cos z} = (-1)^n$$

So, the limit exists and is not zero. Hence, $z = n \pi$ are simple poles.